# Why was this questions closed as "Off-Topic"?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[Why is Victor Creed's Hair black in "X-men Origins: Wolverine"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60119/why-is-victor-creeds-hair-black-in-x-men-origins-wolverine)

This question was closed as off-topic. My question is why? I want someone, maybe the people that closed it, to explain why it was closed. The explanation I got wasn't very explanatory.

I thought it was on-topic due to the fact that I am inquiring about a possibly sci-fi element. The series I am talking about is definitely a sci-fi series.

All I want is a explanation. I am not trying to cause a argument or insult someone. If anyone can answer my question that would be appreciated. I really want a answer for the X-Men question as I find it peculiar and Sabretooth is one of my favourite characters.

Comment: I didn't close it, but I surely would have. What sci-fi related reason could possibly be garnered from the hair color of an actor in a movie vs a comic series. Such a minor difference is barely worth noticing at all and can be attributed to media translation issues and actor choices.

Comment: @Thaddeus I thought it was valid and the closers are mentioned in the old edits of my Meta questions(just so we all know :)). All I wanted was a close reason now that I know this question is not going to get a answer(in its current condition) on this site I will go to another site. I really think the reason is something bigger and not minor(for the hair color). If it didn't matter the makers of the film could have just bought cheap hair dye. But it must have meant something to continuity. Thanks for helping me, either way.

Answer (score 4):

I was one of those who originally voted to close this question. If memory serves, I felt that the questioner was more interested in the *stylistic* choice of hair colour for the actor that played Sabretooth in the films, rather than a question about whether that coloration had any bearing on his character in the film.

Based on the recent comments from the OP, I've been convinced that the question is indeed valid, albeit I agree with @phantom42's comments that it is a poor question in general.

As such, I've reopened it (with my super-dooper new moderator powers) and downvoted it.

Comment: For the record, neither @thaddeus or myself were moderators when we voted to close this question.

Comment: Thank You for giving me a reason :) I have since asked on other sites and would love any advice on how to better the question. Because all the comments do not help me understand how to better the post. Maybe for new users and as a new feature a Scifi and Fantasy Sandbox could be set up. Like the [Questions Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on Worldbuilding. I know that you weren't a mod when you closed the post as I voted in the new mod election, but I was saying that since you now are I you should be ready to really help me :)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't close the question, but this is my guess:

Having black vs blonde hair is not sci-fi related. That is,  the question is about hair colour,  not sci-fi.

Comment: I thought something like that, that is why I wanted the closers to explain. Because it could be about Scifi right, we don't why they change his hair. And don't possible Scifi questions count, no one mentioned the Scope excluding it when closing. I will go to a different site if it is really off-topic. But I just wanted to understand better here.

Comment: Wait until the closers come and explain. I feel like the answer is a good one in that it explains about Victor and then the hair colour,  but the part that does explain the hair colour has nothing sci-fi about it.

Comment: I wanted something more canon for a answer. But if the answer can be fixed or explained with canon that is good. Thank You Pureferret, I will wait for the closers to explain. They are mods so I should get really good help :)

Comment: We have a good number of other well received behind the scenes questions asking why things were changed by studios/writers. This may not be a "good" question, but I don't at all understand how it's off-topic.